# Using OpenCL in linux and IDEs

Tags: ide, opencl, gpu

For using OpenCL in linux should I have NVIDIA GPU?
In my computer I have an Intel GPU and i3 Intel CPU supported SSE3 and SSE4, I want program whith OpenCL in windows can I use an other IDE than "Visual Studio" for example "Code Blocks"?
Thank you

Comment: I have successfully used codeblocks for OpenCL in linux and Windows. However, you will have little to none plugins or integrated tools.

Comment: It is really easy to get OpenCL running using Visual Studio Express and the SDK from any of the manufacturers.  Be careful if you have multiple platforms installed with multiple devices.  It can be a bit dicey configuring OpenCL until you get some good classes developed.  Personally, I would recommend AMD or Intel for OpenCL development, as NVIDIA seems to lag behind in vector support and in a few other areas.

Answer (score -1):

You can use OpenCL with any GPU, as it can run on a CPU as well (that's one of the strong points of OpenCL vs CUDA and the like).

But if you want OpenCL to actually use your GPU and not (or not only) your CPU, you will have to have a driver for your GPU which supports OpenCL, e.g. AMD or NVIDIA. Intel also lists Intel HD and Intel Iris graphic chips as supported through their OpenCL SDK, but you should probably check what you're actually running on if you want to make sure (e.g. check at the start of your program - see Appendix A).

Also, OpenCL has NOTHING to do with CPU extensions like SSE (specific implementations may use SSE/AVX/whatever CPU extension for better performance, but OpenCL does not require any of those per se), or with the IDE you use, and only very little with operating system. So you're free to use whichever IDE you want to (at the end, the IDE is only the editor you write your code with). In the case of Visual Studio people often tend to mix IDE with compiler, as Visual Studio uses it's own compiler per default, but afaik even there you're free to change it to e.g. the mingw or cygwin provided compiler, or use the icc. (Feel free to correct me on the Visual Studio part as I've only tested it once before completely wiping it forever)

---

Appendix A: How to check which devices can be used by OpenCL on a given system http://dhruba.name/2012/08/14/opencl-cookbook-listing-all-devices-and-their-critical-attributes/

Comment: I am going to download the intel OpenCL SDK and I found that we must have "Microsoft Visual C++* 2010 runtime libraries", see this link: http://software.intel.com/en-us/articles/intel-sdk-for-opencl-applications-2013-release-notes#_System_Requirements_1

Comment: You don't even need an SDK nor libraries. If you use dynamic OpenCL. Like "clew". If you need clew for OpenCL C++ bindings, let me know.

Comment: @griffin, you mention that "OpenCL has NOTHING to do with CPU extensions like SSE". That is incorrect as both AMD and Intel's OpenCL CPU drivers target the SSE/AVX instruction sets.

Comment: @JimV That's the implementation you're talking about, but OpenCL itself does not say anything about CPU extensions (and could as well be implemented without using any of those extensions). But I will amend the paragraph to make it more clear, thanks for pointing that out.

Comment: @DarkZeros You never _need_ any kind of SDK or library for anything. (I don't know clew, but from googling a few mins it still relies on system provided shared libraries, but I might be wrong there). You can do anything those provide yourself as well. But the OP might be interested in what you mention, so if you have a link for that, I'll gratefuly (adding your name to it) add it to the answer to make it easier for others to find as well.